# When I run this code I'm getting error its due to I'm call a module inside folder

Tags: python, module

Need help

I'm maintaining a folder structure in python but when im running the code its is giving me an error "it cannot find module"

folder structure is

> entry.py
>   bin/process.py
>   bin/data.py
>   bin/mineclass.py

entry.py will call process.py and in process.py use, data.py and data.py will use mineclass.py

Code on Github:

https://github.com/SudeepSinghRawat/pythonErrorDemo

If any has any sloution please let me know

Comment: ""it cannot find module" is not a standard Python error. Please post the actual error (ideally with traceback) and the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your issue *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0):

Add the empty file

`bin/__init__.py`

You can find more details here: https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html

Comment: Folders without ``__init__.py`` are namespace package, so the package should work without one.